# How to get the cell's output data from a azure databricks notebook to a file

Tags: azure, databricks

Unable to get a single cell's output to a file in Azure databricks notebook

Tried many ways but unable to get the result.

Can someone help me on this if there is a way or there is no way please let me know.

Thanks and regards,
Prem

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps to export the output of a single cell to a file in Azure Databricks.

- You can use the _ (underscore) variable, which represents the output of the last executed cell in Databricks notebooks.  Assign the output to a variable, like this
  [image]
  Create the directory (if it doesn't exist)
  [image]

You can use standard Python file handling techniques to write the output to a file.
[image]

[image]
**Output to file:**
[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks for the info, but unable to retrive the previous cell's output, instead it is returning only true.
If i had an error in the output of a cell, then i need to get the complete error into a file.

Comment: @ChandPrem Can you provide the source code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use IPython's magic command `%%capture variable_name` to store a databricks cell output into a variable.

```
%%capture capOut
print("something")
print(25)
```

The above code stores stdout, stderr and outputs to `capOut` object.
Calling `capOut.stdout` gives `'something\n25\n'`.

As of now, stderr in databricks doesn't seem to capture python errors/exceptions unless explicitly specified. You can use something like this.

```
%%capture capOut
print("an error", file=sys.stderr)
```

It can then be accessed using `capOut.stderr`, which returns `'an error\n'`.
Although, I'd suggest using `logging` module to log errors, which is captured to stderr by default.

You can then write this to a file as follows.

```
with open("path/to/file.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(f"STDOUT:{capOut.stdout}\n")
    f.write(f"STDERR:{capOut.stderr}")
```